# Rubocop error: Assignment Branch Condition size for a function is too high. How can I decrease this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metrics, rubocop, rubocop-rspec

1.I just started working on ruby and started using Rubocop for following general ruby guidelines but I got Assignment Branch Condition error, is anyone can help me with this?

@months = [{ 1 => 'Jan' }, { 2 => 'Feb' }, { 3 => 'Mar' }, { 4 => 'Apr' }, { 5 => 'May' }, { 6 => 'Jun' },{ 7 => 'Jul' }, { 8 => 'Aug' }, { 9 => 'Sep' }, { 10 => 'Oct' }, { 11 => 'Nov' }, { 12 => 'Dec' }]

```
   def calc_high_low_temp_of_month(date, address)

      high_temp_of_month = []
      min_temp_of_month = []
      max_humid_of_month = []

      @data_exists = false
      year, month = date.split('/')
      month = month.to_i
      month_hash = @months.detect { |x| x[month] }
      month = month_hash[month]
      begin
        arr = Dir.children(address)
      rescue Errno::ENOENT
        puts 'file not found!!!'
        return ''
      end
      arr.each do |elem|
         next unless elem.include?(year.to_s) && elem.include?(month.to_s)

        file_data = []
        File.foreach("#{address}/#{elem}") do |line|
          unless line.strip.empty?
            file_data.push(line)
            @data_exists = true
          end
        end

        splited_data = []
        splited_data = file_data[0].split ','
        index_of_high_temp = splited_data.find_index('Max TemperatureC')
        index_of_min_temp = splited_data.find_index('Min TemperatureC')
        index_of_humidity = splited_data.find_index('Max Humidity')

        (1...file_data.count).each do |index|
          splited_data = file_data[index].split ','
          if index_of_high_temp <= (splited_data.count - 1) && !splited_data[index_of_high_temp].empty?
            high_temp_of_month.push(splited_data[index_of_high_temp].to_i)
          end
          if index_of_min_temp <= (splited_data.count - 1) && !splited_data[index_of_min_temp].empty?
            min_temp_of_month.push(splited_data[index_of_min_temp].to_i)
          end
          next unless index_of_humidity <= (splited_data.count - 1)

          max_humid_of_month.push(splited_data[index_of_humidity].to_i) unless splited_data[index_of_humidity].empty?
        end
      end
      if @data_exists
        min_max_temp_of_month_hash = {}
        min_max_temp_of_month_hash['highTempOfMonth'] = high_temp_of_month
        min_max_temp_of_month_hash['minTempOfMonth'] = min_temp_of_month
        min_max_temp_of_month_hash['maxHumidOfMonth'] = max_humid_of_month
        min_max_temp_of_month_hash
      else
        ''
      end
    end
```

Comment: can you paste the output of rubocop command here?

Comment: Assignment Branch Condition size for calc_high_low_temp_of_month is too high. [<19, 48, 16> 54.05/17] (convention:Metrics/AbcSize)
Cyclomatic complexity for calc_high_low_temp_of_month is too high. [14/7] (convention:Metrics/CyclomaticComplexity)
Method has too many lines. [37/23] (convention:Metrics/MethodLength)
Perceived complexity for calc_high_low_temp_of_month is too high. [14/8] (convention:Metrics/PerceivedComplexity)

Answer (score 1):

The *Assignment, Branch, and Condition Metric* (ABC) counts *Assignments*, *Branches*, and *Conditions*, as the name implies.

If you have too many Assignments, Branches, and Conditions, then the way to fix that is to reduce the amount of at least one of

- Assignments,
- Branches, or
- Conditions.

Just as an example:

Here:

```ruby
splited_data = []
splited_data = file_data[0].split ','
```

You assign `splited_data` and then you *immediately overwrite* that assignment without doing anything else in between. Which means that the first assignment is completely useless, it doesn't do anything at all, and you could just write

```ruby
splited_data = file_data[0].split ','
```

instead.

Another example:

```ruby
min_max_temp_of_month_hash = {}
min_max_temp_of_month_hash['highTempOfMonth'] = high_temp_of_month
min_max_temp_of_month_hash['minTempOfMonth'] = min_temp_of_month
min_max_temp_of_month_hash['maxHumidOfMonth'] = max_humid_of_month
```

These 4 assignments can easily be written as no assignment at all:

```ruby
{
  'highTempOfMonth' => high_temp_of_month,
  'minTempOfMonth' => min_temp_of_month,
  'maxHumidOfMonth' => max_humid_of_month
}
```

It is hard to give good advice because your code is incredibly complex and convoluted. The best approach would be to break the code into multiple separate methods.